# Loop continues looping, even after termination message

Tags: python, input, printing, python-3.8

I am having some trouble with getting `user input` to stop looping after the termination message. Basically, once `0 (zero)` is entered in the `Enter bet` field, the program must print a termination message and end. However, it continues to loop by asking for the next line of input `"Choose a number between 2 and 12"` when it should be skipped.
I know a `break` or `exit()` will fix my problem, but those are not acceptable solutions. Once `0 (zero)` is entered in the `Enter bet` field, I need it to finalize and print a termination messag. Not continue on with the program.

Example NEEDED output:

```
you have $500 in your bank # starting amount
Enter bet (or 0 to quit): 0 
Thanks for playing!
```

What I am getting instead:

```
Enter bet (or 0 to quit): 0
Thanks for playing!
Choose a number between 2 and 12: # where the program continues to run 
# when it shouldn't. The user should only see this input field if they enter
# number above 0
```

This is the code

```
import random

def rollDice(cnt):
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)
    x = int(die1 + die2)
    print('Roll #', cnt, 'was', x)
    return x

def total_bank(bank):
    bet = 0
    while bet <= 0 or bet > min([500,bank]):
        print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
        get_bet = input('Enter your bet (or 0 to quit): ')
        bet = int(get_bet)
        if get_bet == '0': 
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            return bank, bet
        return bank, bet

def get_guess():
    guess = 0
    while (guess < 2 or guess > 12):
        try:
            guess = int(input('Choose a number between 2 and 12: '))
        except ValueError:
            guess = 0
    return guess

prog_info()
bank = 500
guess = get_guess
rcnt = 1

while rcnt < 4:
    rcnt = 0
    bank,bet = total_bank(bank)
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess == rollDice(rcnt+1):
        bank += bet * 2
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+2):
        bank += bet * 1.5
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+3):
        bank = bank
else:
    bank = bank - bet
    if bank == 0:
        print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
        print('Thanks for playing!')
```

**Create a “bank” (variable) with a starting value of $500.**

- Ask the player for a bet
- Must be 0 (zero) or greater and cannot exceed the amount currently in the bank.

**Roll the 2 die**

- If the players guess matched the 1st roll then add double the amount bet to the “bank”
- If the players guess matched the 2nd roll then add 1 ½ times the amount bet to the “bank”.
- If the players guess matched the 3rd roll than add the amount bet to the bank.
  -If the players guess did NOT match any roll then subtract the bet from the “bank”.

Let the player keep on playing until they enter a “0” (zero) as the bet OR when their bank reaches “0” (zero).

- NO USE OF BREAK OR EXIT()

Comment: add an if statement that will break it if it finds the number as zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `0` check should call `exit`

```
    if get_bet == '0': 
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        exit()
```

If you prefer not to use `exit` or `break`, you need to exit the main loop using a condition

- Update `total_bank`

  ```
    if get_bet == '0': 
        print('Thanks for playing!')
    return bank, bet
  ```
- Update the main loop

  ```
  bet = 1  # to start loop

  while rcnt < 4 and bet: # exit loop if bet=0
     rcnt = 0
     bank,bet = total_bank(bank)
     if not bet: continue  # exit game if bet = 0
     guess = get_guess()
     if guess == rollDice(rcnt+1):
         bank += bet * 2
     elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+2):
        bank += bet * 1.5
     elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+3):
         bank = bank
  else:
     if bet:  # bet = 0 if game end
         bank = bank - bet
         if bank == 0:
             print(f'You have ${bank} in your bank.')
             print('Thanks for playing!')
  ```

Comment: Is there any way that I can do this without the use of break or exit()?

Comment: This edit worked a lot better, I am finally able to have it print correctly. Thank you so much for the help! This program has driven me crazy for the last 3 weeks.

Answer (score 1):

you're returning to

```
while rcnt < 4:
    rcnt = 0
    bank,bet = total_bank(bank)
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess == rollDice(rcnt+1):
        bank += bet * 2
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+2):
        bank += bet * 1.5
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+3):
        bank = bank
```

after breaking from loop inside `total_bank(bank):`

you can modify the main loop to break if bet==0 by modifying it as follows

```
while rcnt < 4:
    rcnt = 0
    bank,bet = total_bank(bank)
    if bet==0 :
       break;
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess == rollDice(rcnt+1):
        bank += bet * 2
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+2):
        bank += bet * 1.5
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+3):
        bank = bank
```

EDIT - doing it without a break.

Check if bet!=0 before executing the loop.
Just initialise bet to any value other than zero.

```
bet=1
while (rcnt < 4) and (bet!=0):
    rcnt = 0
    bank,bet = total_bank(bank)
    guess = get_guess()
    if guess == rollDice(rcnt+1):
        bank += bet * 2
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+2):
        bank += bet * 1.5
    elif guess == rollDice(rcnt+3):
        bank = bank
```

Comment: But is there a way to do it without a break or exit() statement? I need to be able to do it without those statements, otherwise I would have used break to begin with.

Comment: I've added a way

Comment: I am sorry for so much trouble, but it still is not working. It continues to print the "Choose a number between 2 and 12" input.

Answer (score 0):

> to get your first line of needed output change your print statement to

```
print('You have ${} in your bank.'.format(bank))
```